# MySQL query returns no result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have fields `id` and `date` defined as VARCHAR(16)

When I do this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `members` 
WHERE `id` = '4412040999876'
AND `date` = '201706054783'
```

I get no results.

When I do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `members` 
WHERE `id` = 4412040999876
AND `date` = 201706054783
```

Note - without the quotes - I get the result I am expecting.

**EDIT:** Here is the code used - I am not manually adding quotes. CI's DB class is adding them.

```
public function get_member_match($id, $mem, $field = 'name')
{
    $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM `members`
        WHERE `id` = ?
        AND `" . $field . "` = ?
    ";
    $sql_array = array($id, $mem);
    $q = $this->db->query($sql, $sql_array);
    return $q->result_array();
}
```

And I call this function as:

```
$this->members_model->get_member_match($id, $date, 'date');
```

I output the query, and the variables are matched correctly, no errors, only the quotes.

**Any idea why? I never had this problem before. Working on CodeIgniter 3 using Query Builder.**

**EDIT2:** Summary of findings so far:

1. Localhost (MySQL 5.6.24) works, server (MySQL 5.5.55-0+deb7u1) doesn't.
2. The problem occurs in my code and in PHPMyAdmin on the server but works locally, so I eliminate a code issue.
3. The `show variables like 'char%'` query shows all character set settings identical on local and on the server.
4. Database and fields have the same encoding on both server and local.
5. Does not seem to be a casting issue as many of the comments suggest, as the problem is not present on localhost, only on the server, unless the server has config or other issues.
6. ...?

Comment: .... this is down to data types = date is a string so-to-speak, date should be wrapped in single quotes, if id is an int field - no need for quotes, in fact, don't do quotes at all if it's int

Comment: It's typecasting. Don't quote numbers except for dates

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs But my fields are defined as varchar? I am using CI's query builder, so I am not actually adding any quotes. They library is doing it automatically...

Comment: @clearshot66 okay - so how do I fix this? I am not manually adding the quotes. It is added by CodeIgniter's DB class. I will add the exact code I use on the question.

Comment: Cast it back, like in SQL :CAST(id AS Integer)

Comment: @KobusMyburgh is there no other function? seems pretty dangerous to have a function put quotes around every field that's not id...

Comment: Date is a keyword in mysql

Comment: I used (int) on the inputs to convert to integer, not working. Maybe because these numbers are longer than max size for int in number of characters?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - native CI function I have always used. I never had this happen before.

Comment: @Nomistake if in backticks it does not matter. Changed it to `datex` just in case, still same. Query does not result in error, just not returning a result.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh Ok, not that I was giving a solution, just a comment ;-)

Comment: @KobusMyburgh see my answer and let me know if that helps, syntax is actually CAST(columnName AS INTEGER) = ' ',  if it isn't working that way try CAST(ColumnName As CHARACTER) = ' ';

Comment: @KobusMyburgh then surely that implies the function was altered somewhere else in the code no?

Comment: @KobusMyburgh just curious, why not "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ? AND " . $field . " = ?" ? Why using those quotes?

Comment: @Nomistake as I said, I am not adding the quotes. CI's DB class adds it.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs nope - I did not hack CI's core. I have been doing this for years like this without hassles, that's why I am so confused.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh hm odd - could be something to do with the actual variables you're passing? I'm honestly not sure though

Comment: @KobusMyburgh what happens when you try those query in something like phpadmin? i guess you will get a clearer error...

Comment: No error, just with quotes, no result, without quotes, I get result.

Comment: @Nomistake above comment meant for you - same result in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Could this be some security plugin? as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/security-plugins.html? I am busy trying to speak to the server hosts to see if something like that could be the cause. Does anyone know if this can be the case?

Comment: Looking back at my old questions now. This was resolved by telling CI to use the query raw.

Answer (score 1):

id might be defined as integer in your database. To match against integer fields you do not need to use quotes. Quotes are used when you match against string or text fields.

Comment: It is defined as varchar(16) not int.

Answer (score 1):

This should cast it back from the codeigniter's auto cast:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `members` 
WHERE `id` = '4412040999876'
AND `date` = '201706054783'


SELECT * 
FROM `members` 
WHERE CAST(`id` as INTEGER) = '4412040999876'
AND `date` = '201706054783'
```

Comment: That results in "You have an error in your SQL syntax" - 

    SELECT * 
    FROM `members` 
    WHERE CAST `id` AS INTEGER) = '44...'
    AND `date` = '...'

Comment: I did it through my database and it's functioning fine...do you have the CAST( , what you copied doesn't. If your column is varchar try casting as VARCHAR instead.

Comment: When replacing INTEGER with VARCHAR, I get syntax error. When replacing it with CHAR, the query runs, but gets no result.

Comment: If it pulls results WITHOUT ' ' and none with, it's definitely a typecasting issue just keep googling and testing different patterns of stuff man

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
$this->db->from('members');
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->where($field,$mem);
$q = $this->db->get();
return $q->result_array();
```

Comment: Tried that, thanks, but it does not work. The deeper question though, although I understand that it is a casting issue, is that this is working on my localhost as is, but not on the server, so I am really confused. I have decided to manually clean the user input, and the problem is resolved functionally, but not the way I needed it to work.

Comment: its not casting issue.Try to include your table structure and few data with your question.

Answer (score -1):

It's because the quotes imply that it is a string, whereas id field is an integer and must be written without quotes.

Same for date. Internally date is stored as an integer but is able to convert string into dates as long as they have an appropriate format

Comment: see first line of question. Both are defined as varchar(16) in my table...

Comment: Are you sure ? Check again your DB definition. I used CI for some projects and never added quotes automatically. Log your query. log_message('debug', $query);